# Recreate a binary matrix with least "XOR" operations

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, binary, xor

This was a highschool-degree coding contest question a while back. The basic idea was to recreate a painting of black and white with only rectangular XOR operations, or that's what they called it.

### The problem

Let us assume we have this painting we are trying to recreate (represented as a binary matrix, 0 being black and 1 being white):

```
1 0 0
1 1 1
1 0 1
```

One way of recreating the painting would be the following operations:

```
(0, 0) (2, 2)
(1, 0) (2, 0)
(1, 2) (1, 2)
```

The operations are in the form of `(xStart, yStart) (xEnd, yEnd)`

Thus the above operations would do the following, if we start from an all-black canvas:

```
beginning:

    0 0 0
    0 0 0
    0 0 0

after (0, 0) (2, 2) :

    1 1 1
    1 1 1
    1 1 1

after (1, 0) (2, 0) :

    1 0 0
    1 1 1
    1 1 1

after (1, 2) (1, 2) :

    1 0 0
    1 1 1
    1 0 1
```

---

Technicalities about the assignment:

- Winner has the **least** operations.
- One operation should be in the form of `(xStart, yStart) (xEnd, yEnd)`.
- There are no time or space restraints.
- In the assignment, the painting we were trying to recreate was 200x200 in size, and generated with 2000 random XOR operations.

---

### My own ideas

I have come up with a couple of ways to do this. I'll list them here in order of worse to best.

**XOR all the *pixels*:**

We can recreate the painting by simply writing 1 to a blank canvas where a 1 resides in the painting we are trying to recreate. This solution is the simplest and most obvious of all. The number of operations needed is basically the amount of white pixels in the painting.

**XOR all horizontally adjacent whites:**

This is a substantial improvement from the first solution, but still very simple and obvious. In this method we simply XOR all horizontally adjacent whites. In this way, for example the operations

```
(0, 0) (0, 0)
(1, 0) (1, 0)
(2, 0) (2, 0)
```

would be diminished to `(0, 0) (2, 0)`.

**XOR rectangles:**

This I think is a clear follow-up of the previous method, which we can see as XORing rectangles with height of 1 - Now we just add a second dimension to the rectangles, further improving our results. I determined the XORable area by getting the rectangle with the most whites. The improvement is still good.

**XOR the biggest difference:**

This is a slight change from the above methods, and a bit more brute-force. In this method I find the rectangle with the biggest difference to the painting, and XOR it. For example, if we have the painting

```
1 0 1
0 1 1
0 1 0
```

and an all-black canvas, the biggest difference would be in the rectangle `(0, 0) (2, 1)`, which has a difference of 2. I calculate the difference by getting all the non-same colors of the painting, which is 4 in the above situation, and then subtracting the amount of same colors from it, which in the above situation is 2. So `different_colors - same_colors = difference`.

In the above painting and a blank canvas, there are many rectangles that produce the same difference. One other is `(1, 0) (2, 2)`.

This method gave the smallest improvement from the previous one with large paintings, but an improvement nonetheless. Interstingly, this method sometimes came up with a worse solution than the previous one with small paintings (can't remember how small, though).

---

Any code I had for the described methods above have been long since lost. Can you come up with breath-taking solutions? Is there a magical approach from outer space? I find this question (post) pretty interesting and would like to see if anyone can come up with anything.

---

**About the tags**

I have tagged this with both Java and C++, not because this question concerns particularly those languages, but because I can easily understand any code written in those languages, and with languages with similar syntax.

Comment: Maybe better on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @weston This question isn't meant as a puzzle for the users of stackexchange. I personally want to find a great solution to this problem with the assistance of those users.

Comment: By 'XORing' I presume that you mean 'XORing with 1', i.e., flipping the bits.

Comment: @user1990169 It's simply flipping the bits, yes. 1's become 0's, and 0's become 1's.

Comment: See [explanation at CodeChef (by ACRush)](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/6549/effpaint-editorial).

Comment: @EvgenyKluev nice find. I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

I think, to complete this task, we require to find the coordinates of maximum size sub-matrix containing only zeros.

I can explain that algorithm but I think following link has the best explanation :

[Maximum size sum-matrix with all 1s in binary matrix](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/)

Here solution is for all 1s, we can modify it for all 0s.

Then all we need to do is find the coordinate from maximum value and we can do operation.

I'll update if I can think of some better method.